# Faulting module what does this mean and why does this happen?

Tags: c#, dll, module, fault

I have an apllication written in .net C# and it sporafdically crashes (not responding) the windows event log ahd the following message.
(teh dll it refers to is unmanaged code)

does anyone know what does this exception mean? what might cause this? and what are the ways to solve this?

Faulting application name: Application.exe, version: 4.2.11.0, time stamp: 0x4e8d8e86
Faulting module name:myDll.DLL_unloaded, 
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0000000180004d3c
Faulting module path: myDll.DLL
Report Id: 5608bfd7-f014-11e0-9df7-001cc05d00b7

thanks!

Answer (score 6):

It means that `MyDll.DLL` was unloaded while it still had active code (either running at the time, or waiting to run because it is on the stack or is registered as a callback), so when the program went to execute the code, there was no code there any more. You need to investigate why your DLL is being unloaded and prevent it from being unloaded while it is still has active code.